# Initialize an object on the arraylist.get.set method?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, set

I'm new at this.
I have something like this:

```
    {
        libri.get(i).setUtenteAssegnato(**Utente**);   How do i create an Utente instance with user inputs?
    }
```

Utente class:

```
package Biblioteca;

public class Utente 
{
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;

    public Utente (String unNome, String unCognome)
    {
        this.nome=unNome;
        this.cognome=unCognome; 
    }

    public String getNome() 
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() 
    {
        return cognome;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (this.nome + this.cognome);
    }

}
```

This is the Libro class, with setUtenteAssegnato method:

```
package Biblioteca;

public class Libro 
{
    private int codice;
    private String titolo;
    private Utente utenteAssegnato;

    public Libro (int unCodice, String unTitolo)
    {
        this.codice = unCodice;
        this.titolo = unTitolo;
        this.utenteAssegnato = null;
    }

    public Utente getUtenteAssegnato()
    {
        return this.utenteAssegnato;
    }

    public void setUtenteAssegnato(Utente utenteAssegnato) 
    {
        this.utenteAssegnato = utenteAssegnato;
    }

    public int getCodice() 
    {
        return codice;
    }

    public String getTitolo() 
    {
        return titolo;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (this.codice + this.titolo + this.utenteAssegnato);
    }
}
```

This is the class i'm having problem with:

```
package Biblioteca;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Biblioteca 
{
    List<Libro> libri = new ArrayList<Libro>();
    List<Utente> utenti = new ArrayList<Utente>();

    public Biblioteca ()
    {

    }

    public void aggiungiUtente (String unNome, String unCognome)
    {
        Utente u1 = new Utente (unNome, unCognome);
        utenti.add(u1);
    }

    public void aggiungiLibro(int unCodice, String unTitolo)
    {
        Libro l1 = new Libro (unCodice, unTitolo);
        libri.add(l1);
    }

    public void creaPrestito (int unCodice, String unCognome)
    {
        boolean codiceTrovato = false;
        boolean cognomeTrovato = false;
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=0; i<libri.size(); i++)
        {
            if (libri.get(i).getCodice() == (unCodice))
            {
                System.out.println("Codice trovato. ");
                codiceTrovato = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Codice non trovato. ");
            }
        }

        for (j=0; j<utenti.size(); j++)
        {
            if (utenti.get(j).getCognome().equals(unCognome))
            {
                System.out.println("Utente trovato. ");
                cognomeTrovato = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Utente non trovato. ");
            }
        }
        if (codiceTrovato && cognomeTrovato)
        {
            **libri.get(i).setUtenteAssegnato(Utente);**
        }
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        String stampa = ", ";
        for(Libro d : libri) 
        {
            stampa += d.toString();
        }
        return stampa;
    }
}
```

Basically, i don't know how to set the object in the arraylist (i) position from input (it should be 2 strings, right?) 
Do i have to create another instance of Utente?

Comment: Is this line of code "**libri.get(i).setUtenteAssegnato(Utente);**" you're having the problem of setting the object? (By the way, what do you suppose the value of 'i' here? looks like it will always be equals to "**libri.size()**" )

Comment: Yep, that line.
The (i) value *should* be equal to the position of "unCodice" or "unCognome"